# understanding fundamentals of recursive functions

Tags: javascript, recursion

I can't seem to fully understand the fundamentals off recursive functions. We have this code:

```
function myself (n) {
if (n <= 1) {
    return 1;
}
return n * myself(n-1);
}
myself(5);
```

I get that 5 would be multiplied by 4 equals to 20 and then 20 multiplied by 3 and so on but what I don't quite get is how can 'n' be two different numbers in one function.

Comment: `n` is local to an invocation of the function, not to the function itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @still_learning can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: I think it goes like this https://sketch.io/render/sk-12d201670252aff23415d719d49cebbf.jpeg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how can 'n' be two different numbers in one function

Variable scope exists for a function *invocation*, not a function definition.

Each call to `myself` gets an `n` variable of its very own, which is unrelated to the previously existing `n`s.

Comment: Was typing dozens of lines about the virtual machine's call stack when I read your answer. Could not agree more with @TomerW.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helped a lot.

Comment: @Quentin so i thought that i got it but i didn't :D so when myself(n-1) finishes the 'function myself (n // is it 4 now?). And when n is multiplied by n-1 where does the result go? I guess i don't fully understand the scope either....

Comment: "when myself(n-1) finishes the 'function myself (n // is it 4 now?)." — Which `n`? As I said, there are multiple `n`s

Comment: "And when n is multiplied by n-1 where does the result go?" — That never happens. `n - 1` is the argument to a function call, it is the return value of that function call which is multiplied by `n`. As for where it goes, there is a `return` statement on the left hand side, so it is returned to wherever it was called from.

Answer (score 2):

`n` is a local variable. Your example would *execute* as follows.

```
myself(5) 
return 5 * myself(4)
return 5 * (return 4 * myself(3))
return 5 * (return 4 * (return 3 * myself(2)))
return 5 * (return 4 * (return 3 * (return 2 * myself(1))))
return 5 * (return 4 * (return 3 * (return 2 * return 1)))
return 5 * (return 4 * (return 3 * (return 2 * 1)))
return 5 * (return 4 * (return 3 * 2))
return 5 * (return 4 * 6)
return 5 * 24
return 120
```

`n` contains a reference to the number parameter at each invocation.